# SSO using SAML 2.0 for Scala Play web application

Tags: playframework, saml-2.0, deadbolt

I am building a scala play web application and I need to build the SSO functionality with an IdP which support SAML v2.0. In addition to SSO, I need to build authorization mechanism within the application based on the roles received from IdP as an attribute of Authentication Assertion message.

I am new to SAML and SSO area. Based on some quick learning about the SAML and available module options in Play scala, I see below options to use with scala play web application,

- Play-pac4J (for authentication and authorization)
- play2-auth (for authentication and authorization)
- Play-pac4J (for authentication) + Deadbolt (for authorization)

If someone having prior experience, please suggest me the best option to build a secure and a quick solution for SSO and authorization in scala play web application.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have some code snippet that explains your problem?

Comment: I didn't start the code yet about SSO. I am trying to analyze the possible options to choose for. I came across about the above options.
I thought to check with others who might have worked on such need.